# itemize environment with a bracket

Tags: itemize

I want to enclose an itemize environment with a bracket inside an itemize environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{42}, leftmargin=2cm]
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II
        \begin{itemize}
                    \left. 
                          \begin{array}{ll}
        \item SubExample II-1
        \item SubExample II-2
                          \end{array}
                      \right \}=Text
         \end{itemize}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
                \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to do that in itemize environnment

Please Prof. Harish Kumar what can i do in this case  with long text and short text and vice-versa as you see below :

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},overlay,remember picture] \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{A}};}

%% syntax
%%%\mybrace{<first>}{<second>}[<Optional text>]
\NewDocumentCommand\mybrace{mmo}{%
\IfValueTF {#3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east) node[midway, right=0.1cm] {$=$}node[midway, right=0.5cm,text=black,text width = 2in,] {{#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II
        \begin{itemize}
        \item long text bla bla bla\tikzmark{a}
        \item short text bla\tikzmark{b}
         \end{itemize}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
\end{itemize}
\mybrace{a}{b}[Text comes here to describe these to items and justify for your case]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},overlay,remember picture] \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{A}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II
        \begin{itemize}                    
        \item SubExample II-1\tikzmark{a}
        \item SubExample II-2\tikzmark{b}
         \end{itemize}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (a.north east) -- (b.south east) node[midway, right=0.1cm] {$=$}node[midway, right=0.5cm,text=black,text width = 2in,] {Text comes here to describe these to items and justify for your case};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**With a macro**

You can make a macro, if you end up using it for many times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},overlay,remember picture] \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{A}};}

%% syntax
%%%\mybrace{<first>}{<second>}[<Optional text>]
\NewDocumentCommand\mybrace{mmo}{%
\IfValueTF {#3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east) node[midway, right=0.1cm] {$=$}node[midway, right=0.5cm,text=black,text width = 2in,] {{#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II
        \begin{itemize}
        \item SubExample II-1\tikzmark{a}
        \item SubExample II-2\tikzmark{b}
         \end{itemize}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
\end{itemize}
\mybrace{a}{b}[Text comes here to describe these to items and justify for your case]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Response to the edited query

Here we make some assumptions:

1. The sub items can have variable length
2. But they are short enough not to span multiple lines (for if they do, then description becomes meaningless)

With these assumptions, you can put the sub itemize environment inside a `minipage` of width equal to `0.5\textwidth`. You can vary this width as per your need.

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item SubExample II-1 just more length\tikzmark{a}
        \item SubExample II-2\hfill\tikzmark{b}
         \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
\end{itemize}
\mybrace{a}{b}[Text comes here to describe these to items and justify for your case]
```

Another option will be to put each sub item inside a `\parbox` of width `0.5\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},overlay,remember picture] \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {\phantom{A}};}

%% syntax
%%%\mybrace{<first>}{<second>}[<Optional text>]
\NewDocumentCommand\mybrace{mmo}{%
\IfValueTF {#3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east) node[midway, right=0.1cm] {$=$}node[midway, right=0.5cm,text=black,text width = 2in,] {{#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,decoration={brace,amplitude=1ex}]
  \draw[decorate,thick] (#1.north east) -- (#2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  Example I
   \item Example II \par
      %\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{SubExample II-1 just more length as they come here}\tikzmark{a}
        \item \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{SubExample II-2}\tikzmark{b}
         \end{itemize}
%      \end{minipage}
    \item Example III
    \item Example IV
\end{itemize}
\mybrace{a}{b}[Text comes here to describe these to items and justify for your case]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @@Harish Kumar  Please Prof. Harish Kumar  Check the second code with marco doesn't work !!

Comment: @Educ It works, but you have to compile it atleast 2-3 times. Did you? :) And you have to have `xparse` package installed.

Comment: @@Harish Kumar  Please Prof. Harish Kumar i upadate my question :what can i do in this case with long text and short text

Comment: @Educ Please see the update at the end.